# CKEditor error, Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'extend' on 'Selection': 1 is larger than the given node's length

Tags: ckeditor

After setting blurDelay = 0, then click Bold and click Paste in toolbar, it will throw the error below.

Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'extend' on 'Selection': 1 is larger than the given node's length.

CK version:"4.4.6",revision:"08188c4"

Only in Chrome, IE and FF will be fine

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfine2/98rwv6Lt/

bug ticket: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13241

Javascript code.

```
CKEDITOR.focusManager._.blurDelay = 0; 

var ck = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    fullPage: true
});

ck.on( "blur", function( evt ){
    console.log(this.getData());
});
```

Comment: What's the question? If it's a bug report you should rather report it on http://dev.ckeditor.com

Comment: The question is in our code, it will lose focus because of the error.

Comment: Thanks, I will report a bug.

Comment: I wrote my comment before j.swiderski answered. And his answer is right - `blurDelay` is a private property, so you shouldn't touch it. If you changed it, then it's not a bug to be reported, hence we closed http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13241#comment:1

Comment: OK, got that, thanks.

Comment: I am getting this error on an inline editor but only when:
1) "enterMode" : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
2) document ends with an empty line (just hit enter on the last line).
--
CKEDITOR recomments using CKEDITOR.ENTER_P due to semantics, but nothing to do with this error.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your test case and there is error being thrown in Blink browsers only (IE and FF work fine) **but you are manipulating private property**
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager._-property-blurDelay **which is for internal use of CKEditor only**.

One of the reasons we use properties like this one is get rid-of subtle differences between browsers or errors that may get thrown in certain scenarios. **When you leave this property untouched there is no error** and I think that sums it up. You should not manipulate editor internal properties.

Comment: Got that, but our code depends on blurDelay = 0 property, so do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you encounter is probably related to :
https://github.com/ryancramerdesign/ProcessWire/issues/1335

> The issue is that CKEditor's getData() method fails (and produces a JS error) when called before the field is blurred, after certain conditions (like inserting an image)

It was a bug affecting chrome, opera and safari. Throwing the same JS error.
Bug FIXED since CKE v4.5.5

Still to be tested with your modification of blurDelay though.